# Maven dependency plugins

Tags: java, maven

Hi i have a problem starting my project on IntelliJ.The plugins who are installed in my Maven dependency are having error to handle it.I tried to update the repo in indexed maven repository but same error appears,also i reinstall the intelliJ and again its the same.The following images contains the problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable the use plugin registry option within the Maven settings as follows:

1. Click File Settings.
2. Expand Build, Execution, Deployment Build Tools Maven
3. Check Use plugin registry.
4. Click OK or Apply.

May be its help you.